# Jquery Menu Hide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

```
<div class="tools">TOOLS
     <ul>
         <li class="toolone">First
             <div class="plugin">
                 <select>Option
                      <optios></options
                 </select>
             </div>
         </li>
     <ul>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toolone').click(function () {
            $(this).find('.plugin').toggle(200);
        });
    });
```

Hide show works perfect, but when I click on Inner Select option within li even it closes. 
I tried event.stopPropagation();

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toolone').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.plugin').toggle(200);
    });
 $('.toolone select').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   })

 });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/31/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, Worked!

Comment: @Vinayak - If you happy with Learner answer please mark it as accept Otherwise someone keep posting the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there was error in your html. Updated your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="tools">TOOLS
     <ul>
         <li class="toolone">First
             <div class="plugin">
                 <select>
                      <option>abc</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Secondly, you must explicitly handle clicking of select to stop event propagation:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toolone').click(function () {
            $(this).find('.plugin').toggle(200);
        });
        $('.toolone select').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

See the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOUWyeItiUlFOatbGTxo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.toolone').click(function (e) {
        if(e.target !== this) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).find('.plugin').toggle(200);

     });
   });
```